# How to render gltf from binary?

Tags: 3d, gltf

I've been given a csv file with rows of objects, each one containing various data and each row has an "Element Mesh" column in a format such as:

(this snippet goes on and on) after the end...
data:model/gltf-binary;base64,Z2xURgIAAACMCAAASAMAAEpTT057ImFzc2V0Ijp7ImNvcHlya

It looks like some kind of gltf data exported into binary? Is there a way to display each of these rows? I thought maybe I could just copy and paste (minus the "data:") into a file and save it with a GLB or GLTF extension. No luck. Do I have to create a JSON file and then have this binary stream as the value of a field?

Answer (score 2):

This is what's known as a "Data URI" or "Data URL" ([Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) says it was renamed, and explains the structure in more detail).

The short answer is, you must base64-decode everything after the `base64,` part at the start of the string.  Various programming environments come with helpers for this.  For example in JavaScript, it's just `atob(string)`, but be warned that you may get back the binary contents of a GLB file.

The MIME type shown here is `model/gltf-binary`, which indicates that the base64-encoded contents are in the binary form of the glTF format, meaning they should match the contents of a `*.glb` file when decoded.

What to do with the file contents from there depends on what platform, language, environment, and rendering engine you have at your disposal here.

Comment: I was hoping to try something as simple as possible.. like just taking everything after the "base64," and dump it into a text file in notepad, changing the extension to .glb. It doesn't look like that works. I suppose I was just missing the decode step. I tried taking the decoded string I got from an online decode, but no luck either.

Comment: If you take the entire Data URI (`data:model/gltf-binary;base64,...`) and paste it into the URL bar of a web browser, you should get the decoded `.glb` file back.