# How can import list of gltf-binary format into 3D eidting software and export it back along with element IDs

Tags: blender, mesh, gltf

I hope you guys are doing well. I have a question regarding gltf binary.

This question is similar to this link however I am trying to get them imported into any 3d software for editing.
[How to render gltf from binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69164458/how-to-render-gltf-from-binary).

So, I have a CSV file that has the binary information "data"model/gltf-binary;base64,Z2... " along with accompanying information such as Element ID. For the record this is coming from a 3rd party plugin and the models are created from Revit software. I need to modify the origin of these models and I wish to do all of them at the same time and not having to convert each room envelope. After that I need to export them in the same binary format and at the same time retain the information the came with it particularly the Element ID.

As to why I need to do this is because I have several buildings from different files that does not share the same origin. Hence when exported and combined together in powerbi (Powerbi only reads internal origins) Building envelopes that is suppose to be sitting next to each other are hundred meters away or rotated in a wrong direction.

I hope you guys are able to provide me useful links to start off. Please let me know if you require more information.

Thank a lot!

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90AZ5.jpg)

I was searching through the web about importing binary format however I need to do this on multiple elements. So far I have not found any solution.

I am expecting to be able to find a software that will read binary gltf group of mesh, be able to modify XYZ,Rotation and be able to export back to CSV along with the information it came with.